# What is the meaning of "when told to" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "when told to" in the following sentence,

> PLC monitors flow sensor to detect if the pump turns on, ***when told
> to***. If it fails to turn on, the PLC receives an alarm. It then
> tells the other pump to start.

?
(Source: TheEngineeringMindset.com)

Does "when told to" mean "when PLC told to detect if the pump turns on" ?
Or does "when told to" mean "when PLC told for us to detect if the pump turns on" ?
What does "when told to" mean?

[image]

Comment: i suppose  - this means - when fl.sensor detect the flow, it communicate to plc and signal to it about this situation.

Comment: If so, does "when told to" mean "when flow sensor told to flow" ?

Comment: what ? what mean "told to flow" ?  when pump is turned on - > the flow is flowed -> the sensor are triggered and send the signal about this to PLC. I think so :)

Comment: What subject is missing in the sentence "when told to"? And what comes after the to preposition? What if the "when told to" sentence is expressed as a complete sentence?  ( when + missing subject + told to + missing content )

Comment: well... i don't know how is it exactly grammatically. :> But i'm Russian, my native language is inflextive-synthetic, not an analytic one with strong order of sentence, and constructions like this isn't problem for me :> Also - Old English was an inflextive  language too, mb, it's some a relict, etc ? :>
Also - i know what is it the PLC clearly and how it work, in general :> Well, in general all this is my opinion only :> 
Literally answer could be : ""when (means "then") sensor told to PLC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when told to" indicates a command or instruction. For example, on a cruise ship, one may be instructed to put on a life vest "when told to" by a crew member. A student may be instructed to only open the test booklet "when told to" -- meaning do not open the test booklet until the command is given.

The sentence above treats the pump as a person who can be "told to" -- i.e. given a command.  The pump receives some sort of signal that "tells" -- i.e. commands -- the pump to turn on.  The PLC monitors the sensor to determine if the pump complied with the command.

Answer (score 0):

"When told to" implies that the PLC has done more than simply supply power to the pump or activate a relay. The word "told" makes me suspect that the pump has some level of smarts (e.g. microcontroller) and that the PLC is communicating to it that it needs to turn on using an instruction set that both the PLC and the pump understand.

Edit: My answer is based on more than what is written or shown in that infographic. I'll update this answer later but, for now, see my comment below.

Comment: If so, does "when told to" mean "when PLC told to the pump" ?

Comment: In the diagram, the PLC seems to be the only candidate to do the telling. Note: I'm drawing my conclusions from more than the words, which are ambiguous or incorrect in multiple ways. Using only the words, "when told to" could mean that rhe PLC only monitors when told to, but that would be a silly design. Also, the PLC wouldn't receive an alarm, it would be what raises the alarm. And there should be a period at the end of the second last line. And there is no indication of when or why the PLC tells  pump 1 to turn on. Or what the pipes are connected to. Or what the white rectangle is. So... ye

Comment: In the first sentence, there is nothing that grammatically implies that the PLC is doing the telling; the pump "is told to", which is a passive construction, so all we know is that *something* told the pump to turn on.

Comment: @stangdon You are correct and I go into more detail in my comment just above yours. I'll edit my answer to reference my comment for now and add a more concise update to the answer later.

Comment: If so, "when told to" mean "Then the pump is told to turn on by something(e.g PLC)." ?